# Unable to login to Ubuntu Permissions Issue?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, home-directory, chmod

Well, I think I royally messed this one up.

In the process of changing permissions in my home directory, I now can't login using any of the 3 accounts I had setup, except for the Guest account.

I was using the chmod command from the terminal and received an error. Well I reboot for whatever reason and like I said, cant login.

Any suggestions for a newbie to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Ubuntu Live CD to navigate to the directories and give yourself Read/Write permission again.

Helpful link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1817291